# In phaser.js capture touch events on the canvas

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm trying to make a simple game that has a single input based on [lessmilk.com's Flappy Bird tutorial](http://blog.lessmilk.com/how-to-make-flappy-bird-in-html5-3/). On the keyboard you hit space to jump, but on touch enabled devices I'd like to just have the users touch anywhere on the canvas to jump.

Looking at the [input docs](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/wiki/Input) it seems straight forward to capture touch input for a sprite, but I'd like the user to be able click/touch anywhere.

What's the "Phaser way" to capture all touch events? Do I need to do something hacky like create an invisible sprite covering the entire canvas? Should I bypass the phaser and just attach DOM event handlers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like I'd been misunderstanding the role of phaser's input manager. I'd been trying to use [`game.input.touch`](http://docs.phaser.io/Phaser.Input.html#touch) to hook those events but I just needed to be using the higher level [`input.onDown`](http://docs.phaser.io/Phaser.Input.html#onDown) event:

```
    // click / touch to jump
    game.input.onDown.add(this.jump, this);
```